# Create folders [filename] dynamically with img extracted from html files with Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, gulp, preprocessor

I'm working with gulp and I have difficulties creating the best worflow for exporting html emails into zip folders (with html file + images).

**I have 3 files like this :**
email01.html
email02.html
email03.html

I would like to **extract images from these html files** and **create folders under /dist** like this :
**email01**
-- email01.html
-- img (only linked to email01)
**email02**
-- email02.html
-- img (only linked to email02)
**email03**
-- email02.html
-- img (only linked to email02)

Right now, I am using [gulp-file-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-assets) to extract images from each html files and to create a img folder in the ./dist folder. However, I don't know how to create one separate folder (img) for each html file. I am using gulp-rename to create one directory per file with html file in it, but I don't understand how to add an img folder with img linked in these directories.

You can see the code here + result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS8KU.png

And here is the important part of the gulp file :

```html
// BUILDING TRIGGERS FOR EXPORT AND TESTING PURPOSES
gulp.task('buildTriggersFolders', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(config.src.triggersExport + '/*.*')
    // Inline CSS in the files
    .pipe(inline({
            applyStyleTags: false,
            applyLinkTags: true,
            removeStyleTags: false,
            removeLinkTags: false,
          removeHtmlSelectors: false
    }))
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      file.dirname = path.join(file.dirname, file.basename);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest.triggersExport + '_build'));
});

// ADDING IMAGES TO FOLDERS
gulp.task('createImgFolder', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(config.src.triggersExport + '/*.*')
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(fileAssets({
        excludes: ['css'],
        includeSrc: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest.triggersExport + '_build'));
});
```

How could I do this ? Should I use gulp-rename + gulp each?

Thanks a lot for your help!